# Ubuntu one on a single computer with Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-one, cloud

I have a single laptop with Ubuntu and Windows 8 in different partitions. All my important files are in the Windows partition so they can be accessed from both environments, and uploaded to Skydrive when I'm on Windows.

The thing is, I use Ubuntu much more often than Windows so I need to migrate my cloud service and it seems that Ubuntu One would be the obvious choice.

Now, I'd like my files to be synchronized in Ubuntu One regardless of the OS I'm running (the same set of files). Can I achieve this without having to duplicate my files in my HD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

If you use ubuntu one on your linux and windows distro the files will be duplicated on your HD, as a ubuntu one folder will be created on both distros and then synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SkyDrive. It appears to be a Windows specific service. If it is, presumably you cannot run it in Ubuntu.
With for instance DropBox you can specify the folder that you want to be synchronized with the cloud. If your Windows folder is accessible in Ubuntu, you can specify it for synchronization. Then you would not duplicate your files locally.